# Why does a test fail with the message "panicked at Box<Any>"?

Tags: rust, panic

Why does this panic?

```
pub fn testbool() -> bool {
    vec!['a', 'd', 'i', 'e', 'p', 'r']
        .iter()
        .enumerate()
        .find(|(_i, &c)| c != 'c')
        .is_none()
}

#[test]
fn test_testbool() {
    assert!(testbool(), true);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b9a925070f78723e154dd4e26da9f99e)

```
---- test_testbool stdout ----
thread 'test_testbool' panicked at 'Box<Any>', src/lib.rs:11:5
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
```

It is probably very simple, but I don't understand it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using [`assert!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.assert.html). This expects that the first argument is a boolean expression. Any subsequent arguments are considered a format string and arguments for that:

```
assert!(testbool(), "Did not work: {}", 42);
```

```
thread 'test_testbool' panicked at 'Did not work: 42'
```

You probably want to remove the second argument to `assert!` or switch to [`assert_eq!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.assert_eq.html).

---

I believe the root issue comes from a [bug (#30143)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/30143) that allows non format strings to be used as a format string, in certain cases.